# How to reinitialize AppleFontSmoothing for your terminal in osx?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

I wanted to change the font on  iterm which was blurred,
so I use this

`defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 3`

which make the apple-native terminal very bad (and blurred), so now I want to go back to my terminal, uninstall iterm and don't touch anything.

I use this command line:

`defaults delete NSGlobalDomain AppleFontSmoothing`

and

`defaults -currentHost delete -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing`

And it doesn't work, please help I miss my terminal.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you entered,

```
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 3
```

should just be changing the boldness of the font. You could try to write it to something less bold like

```
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 1
```

Otherwise, you could try resetting your terminal preferences completely by going to home->Library->Preferences and deleting *com.apple.terminal.plist*

Comment: resetting my terminal preferences completely by deleting com.apple.terminal.plist works very well, thank you